# how to convert excel sheet into mysql database using etl tools

Tags: mysql, excel, etl

I am in need to convert an excel taken as a input into mysql database table. While searching for tools regarding it, I found that ETL tools (eg.pentaho kettle etl tool) . Can any one say whether the tool is correct or any other approach is there to do the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good option but you have to dig into the subject more yourself.

Take a look at [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDxdy_8mOa0) for example (the tool mentioned in the tutorial - Spoon is part of Kettle).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pentaho Data Integration, aka Kettle, will allow you to do that. As would any ETL tool for that matter. You may also find specific tools that are simpler to use for your purpose, installing a multi 100 Mb tool just for that may be a bit overkill.

Comment: can u please suggest some other tool specific for my purpose